# __str__ example in django tutorial not working

Tags: django, string, printing

I can't get the **str** to work in django tutorial when printing the object texts. This is the code in the models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.question_text)
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.choice_text)
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

In the python shell, I write the following:

```
from first_app.models import Question, Choice
```

When I invoke the **str** function, I get this:

```
Question.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Question: Question object>, <Question: Question object>, <Question: Ques
tion object>]>
```

I even tried print function and got the same result:

```
print(Question.objects.all())
<QuerySet [<Question: Question object>, <Question: Question object>, <Question: Ques
tion object>]>
```

Comment: What version of Python and Django are you using?

Comment: I am using django version (1, 11, 8, 'final', 0) and python version is 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 15:10:56) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials are for Python 3. If you are using old Python use `__unicode__` method instead of `__str__` or use `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator on you model's class to work with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Note, if the tutorial does not mention `__unicode__` it must be because they are using the tutorial for Django 2.0, which only works with Python 3 anyway. They should ensure they are reading the correct version of the tutorial for the version of Django they are actually using.

Comment: I added the  python_2_unicode_compatible and still didn't work. I use django version (1, 11, 8, 'final', 0).

Comment: Found the problem. I had defined Question and Choice classes twice!

Comment: @Ehsan Good! I think it's better to delete the question.

Answer (score -2):

You wrote wrong **str** function for Question model.
**Should be:**

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

**instead of:**

```
def __str__(self):
        return (self.question_text)
```

Comment: I removed the parenthesis and still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Adding parenthesis will do no harm although it's not a good style to add redundant stuff.